# How to filter metrics in output by namespace in SparkMetrics?

Tags: apache-spark, properties, configuration-files, metrics

I have my own metric Namespace (**MyMetricNamespace**):

```
application_1551098139443_0001.driver.TrajectoryCreationApp.MyMetricNamespace.RestProcessorTimer
```

Is it possible to setup in metrics.properties config file ConsoleSink to flush only metrics from my namespace?